# Importing presale wallet on to Kraken

Tags: wallets, import, presale

Anyone know an (easy way) to import a pre sale wallet onto Kraken?
They used to have this [tool](https://www.kraken.com/ether) but it doesn't seem to work anymore?

Thanks

Comment: In what way isn't it working? Perhaps a good place to start would be to contact them, here: https://www.kraken.com/about/contact